# mongodb collection not updating properly

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

so I've added few more lines in the mongo collection of userDB using the code below, first I only had 1 obj in the collection then added few more.

```
db.userDB.insert([{},{},{}])
```

so when I do db.userDB.find() I should see 4 objs in the collection however it only showing me 3 objs I newly added excluding the one I've added before.

Now I'm calling the obj from my angularJs its only showing me the old obj and the network header says Status Code:304 Not Modified, in my console I should get 4 objs. I've restarted the mongo and node server but still not getting the other objs.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to two different DBs. You can check this by running .find({}) in your code and in the console and see if they match.

Comment: I only have 1 db which is called userDB, also this should be a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your DB is called userDB, this won't work, as the insert command is done at the collection level.  You need the collection name, so the command should be:

```
db.collection_name.insert([{},{},{}])
```

you can find all your collection names in your database with the following commands from the mongo shell:

```
use userDB
show collections
```

Comment: the collection name is userDB; I've added a new item using db.userDB.insert({}) which works fine, tried to .find() it and its showing 4 items but calling the db in angular return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/userDB'
   }) only shows the old item.

Comment: redo everything and its okay now, seems like my mongo is running so slow.